# Java language spec: LambdaExpression in Java ConditionalExpression

Tags: java, language-features

In the Java 8 specification there is the following [syntax description of the conditional operator ?:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConditionalExpression) :

```
ConditionalExpression:
ConditionalOrExpression
ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression
ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : LambdaExpression
```

I understand the first two lines. But why is the third line necessary? What is so special about a LamdaExpression that it needs to be declared explicitly, here? I don't see this discussed in the following text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know the answer, but it's weird.

Here is a quote from chapter 15:

> Precedence among operators is managed by a hierarchy of grammar
>   productions. The lowest precedence operator is the arrow of a lambda
>   expression (->), followed by the assignment operators. Thus, all
>   expressions are syntactically included in the LambdaExpression and
>   AssignmentExpression nonterminals:
>
> Expression: LambdaExpression  AssignmentExpression

The ConditionalExpression is a part of AssignmentExpression:

> AssignmentExpression: ConditionalExpression  Assignment

As you quote, the third part of `ConditionalExpression` can be only a `ConditionalExpression`, not an `Expression`.

Making the third part into `Expression` would include undesirable things like `Assignment`:

```
a? b : c=d // bad idea?
```

But, limiting the third part to `ConditionalExpression` rather than `Expression` leaves out `LambdaExpression`, so now it needs to be added explicitly with

> ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : LambdaExpression

This actually brings the next question: how come `Assignment`is OK in the second part of conditional expression but not in the third?